# Sample whole number from distribution with average less than 1

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, synthetic-data

I am trying to create some simulated data, where for each participant, the average number of events that occur in a given week can be any positive number, but usually in the range of 0 to 5.  Trouble is, a lot of the time the average is small, like 0.25.  I can only sample whole numbers, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  How do I sample from these distributions and still maintain their distribution average over all weeks?

(If the averages were all between 0 and 1, and those were my only options, I would just sample a random number between 0 and 1 and return a 1 if it was less than the average).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sample from a discrete distribution, the [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) sounds like a good fit here.

Comment: Poisson looks like it would be perfect here, but if OP didn't like the mean = variance aspect, they could also sample from a negative binomial distribution, which is similar but doesn't require that restriction.

Comment: Thanks both.  I'm trying to do this in excel, and I found a nice way to do this using inverse binomial here - https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/3hsdyg/why_doesnt_excel_have_a_poissoninv_function/cua5371